# Stubbing out a promise inside a method using chai and sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai, sinon-chai

My function under test looks roughly like this;

```
  function doThing(data, callback) {

    externalService.post('send').request(data)
        .then(() => {
          if (callback) { callback(); }
        })
        .catch((message) => {
          logger.warn('warning message');
          if (callback) { callback(); }
        });
  }
```

And I am trying to test this using Chai and Sinon.

I've tried following different guides, my current incantation looks like;

```
const thingBeingTested = require('thing-being-tested');
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
require('sinon-as-promised');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('The Thing', () => {  
  it('should run a callback when requested and successful', done => {

    const externalService = { post: { request: sinon.stub() } };
    const callback = sinon.spy();

    externalService.post.request.resolves(callback);

    doThing({...}, callback);
    expect(callback).to.have.been.called;
    done();
  });
});
```

I cannot get `externalService.post` stubbed out correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am completely new to Chai and Sinon – so fully expect to be doing something stupid.

Comment: Have you considered using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) that proxies nodejs require in order to allow overriding dependencies during testing? Its a useful tool to use when testing in `nodejs` and does make the testing simpler in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @hyprstack - I'd never heard of that. I will have a look to see if it makes sense for this use case (in my example I had one test, but of course there are a few other things that need exercised).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doThing` function has no access to `const externalService` from your test. I will assume that your main file has smth like

```
const externalService = require('./external_service');
```

to get it.

In your test you should get the same `externalService` too:

```
describe(..., () => {
    it(..., () => {
        // adjust the path accordingly
        const externalService = require('./external_service');
```

and then mock its method:

```
sinon.stub(externalService, 'post').returns({
    request: sinon.stub().resolves(callback)
});
```

Then you can call `doThing` and analyze the results.

After the test is complete, don't forget to restore the original `post` by

```
externalService.post.restore();
```